# PHP mysql_real_escape_string(); whats the correct method using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

its a little difficult to explain. I've build the mysql function which works fine and with the depreciation of mysql I will need to change this function to use mysqli rather than the mysql method. 
I current have:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host", "username", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$Password = hash_hmac('sha512', $_POST['pass'], '&R4nD0m^');
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '{$Username}' AND password = '{$Password}'") or die(mysql_error());
    $Query_Res = mysql_fetch_array($Query, MYSQL_NUM);
    if($Query_Res[0] === '1')
    {
        //add session
        header('Location: newpage.php');
    }
            else {
                echo 'failed login';
            }
```

Now I've applied mysqli to this and it's not returning any data or errors but the function still complies.

```
$log = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass");
$log->select_db("db");
$Username = $log->real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$Password = hash_hmac('sha512', $_POST['pass'], '&R4nD0m^');
$qu = $log->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '{$Username}' AND password = '{$Password}'");
    $res = $qu->fetch_array();
    if($res[0] === '1'){
        //add session
        header('Location: newpage.php');
    }
    else {
        $Error = 'Failed login';
        sleep(0.5);
    }
    echo $res['username'].'              hello';
}
```

But I'm unsure on why this is wrong. I know it's probably a simply answer

Comment: @E_p that's the word I was looking for! thanks

Comment: Rather than use string escaping, please learn about using parametrized queries using PDO. It saves you from having to escape strings all the time, and therefore you don't run the risk of forgetting to escape one. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html shows examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to have it as an answer:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

e.g.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check if the connection is establishing before using `real_escape_string()`

```
if ($log->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$log->connect_errno.")".$log->connect_error;
}
```

afaik, there's no problem with `$log->real_escape_string($_POST['user']);`